# Alert function in react native

Tags: php, reactjs, react-native

I have set an alert message on the api script but when it successful run on the frontend wont be able to prompt the alert successful message

here my code, this is the frontend code which expected to return the message from the server

```
fetch(InsertAPIURL, {
        mode:'no-cors',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(Data)
        })
        .then((response) =>response.json())
        .then((responseJson)=>{
        Alert.alert(responseJson);
        }).catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error"+error);
        })
```

here is the backend script code

```
$register = mysqli_query($CN, $insertuserid);

    if ($register) {
        $Message = "Member has been registered successfully";
        $EncodedData=json_encode($Message);
        echo $EncodedData;
    }
        
    else {
        echo "Server Error... please try latter";

    }
```

after execute the data successful insert into the server but it wont prompt anything hope u guys help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Backend Php: you write the following below:

```html
//backend php
if(ok){
 echo json_encode(array("success"=>1,"messsage"=>"successfully"));
}
else{
  echo json_encode(array("success"=>0,"messsage"=>"Error Register"));
}


//frontEnd React
fetch(URL,options).then(res=>res.json()).then(result=>{
  if(result.success===1){
    //write code successfully
    Alert.
  }
  else{
   //write code error register
    Alert.
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Alert Doc: https://reactnative.dev/docs/alert#alert

```
static alert(title, meesage?, buttons?, options?)
```

Parameters:

| NAME | TYPE | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| title | string | The dialog's title. Passing null or empty string will hide the title. |
| message | string | An optional message that appears below the dialog's title. |
| buttons | Buttons | An optional array containing buttons configuration. |
| options | Options | An optional Alert configuration for the Android. |

You can only use string, null, and empty type in the title.
`responseJSON` is not valid type.

```
fetch(InsertAPIURL, {
        mode:'no-cors',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(Data)
        })
        .then((response) =>response.json())
        .then((responseJson)=>{
        Alert.alert(responseJson);
        }).catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error"+error);
        })
```

to

```
fetch(InsertAPIURL, {
        mode:'no-cors',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(Data)
        })
        .then((response) =>response.json())
        .then((responseJson)=>{
        Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson));
        }).catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error"+error);
        })
```